# Get string clean for json_decode

Tags: php, json

sadly, I've been trying to convert a string into an array using json_decode for several hours now.

The string is treated as UTF-8 encoded according to mb_detect_encoding and looks like the following in original:

```
{
"cBestellHinweis":"2222222 Personalisierung: Max Test
222323222 Personalisierung: Für diesen Artikel nicht angefordert.
3333333 Personalisierung: Lalalala
",
"cExterneAuftragsnummer":"66666666666",
"support":"false",
"cBestellNr":"66666666666",
"bestellPositions":[{
"kBestellPos":"2322222",
"legacyOrderItemId":"2323",
"title":"Holzbild Geschenk Geburtstag &quot;Back in&quot; - personalisierbar zum Hinstellen/Aufhängen optional beleuchtet, Geburtstag Mädchen Geschenk 30 Geburtstag - 1991 S - mit Beleuchtung",
"quantity":"1",
"sku":"222222222222",
"amazonSKU":"",
"articletype":"wandlampe",
"cobotFile":"Artprint",
"variationen":"Farbe=30 Geburtstag - 1991;Größe=S - mit Beleuchtung"
},{
"kBestellPos":"232222",
"legacyOrderItemId":"3423",
"title":"Holzbild Geschenk Geburtstag &quot;Back in&quot; - personalisierbar zum Hinstellen/Aufhängen optional beleuchtet, Geburtstag Mädchen Geschenk 20 Geburtstag - 2001 L - mit Beleuchtung",
"quantity":"1",
"sku":"3333333333333",
"amazonSKU":"",
"articletype":"wandlampe",
"cobotFile":"Artprint",
"variationen":"Farbe=20 Geburtstag - 2001;Größe=L - mit Beleuchtung"
},{
"kBestellPos":"23232",
"legacyOrderItemId":"232323",
"title":"Holzbild Geschenk Geburtstag &quot;Back in&quot; - personalisierbar zum Hinstellen/Aufhängen optional beleuchtet, Geburtstag Mädchen Geschenk 30 Geburtstag - 1991 L - ohne Beleuchtung",
"quantity":"1",
"sku":"44444444444444",
"amazonSKU":"",
"articletype":"wandbild",
"cobotFile":"Artprint",
"variationen":"Farbe=30 Geburtstag - 1991;Größe=L - ohne Beleuchtung"
}],
"anzahl":"3",
"istBezahlt":"true"
}
```

Only some values are changed for public.
The text contains various non-printed characters like: \r\n
These seem to be the problem in the source. Simply removing them all does not work, since the line breaks within the values must be preserved.
After many different approaches, this one seems to get me the farthest (step-by-step):

```
$cache = $json_string;
$cache = preg_replace('/(\r\n|\r|\n)+/', "\n", $cache);
$cache = preg_replace('/\\n\"/', '"', $cache);
$cache = preg_replace('/\"\\n/', '"', $cache);
$cache = preg_replace('/\\"/', '"', $cache);
```

With this I should get the following back. The German umlauts aren't a problem in online tool:

```
{"cBestellHinweis":"22222 Personalisierung: Max Test\n222233 Personalisierung: Für diesen Artikel nicht angefordert.\n55555555 Personalisierung: Lalalala\n","cExterneAuftragsnummer":"666666","support":"false","cBestellNr":"666666","bestellPositions":[{"kBestellPos":"222","legacyOrderItemId":"232323","title":"Holzbild Geschenk Geburtstag &quot;Back in&quot; - personalisierbar zum Hinstellen\/Aufh\u00e4ngen optional beleuchtet, Geburtstag M\u00e4dchen Geschenk 30 Geburtstag - 1991 S - mit Beleuchtung","quantity":"1","sku":"23223323","amazonSKU":"","articletype":"wandlampe","cobotFile":"Artprint","variationen":"Farbe=30 Geburtstag - 1991;Gr\u00f6\u00dfe=S - mit Beleuchtung"},{"kBestellPos":"2222","legacyOrderItemId":"2323","title":"Holzbild Geschenk Geburtstag &quot;Back in&quot; - personalisierbar zum Hinstellen\/Aufh\u00e4ngen optional beleuchtet, Geburtstag M\u00e4dchen Geschenk 20 Geburtstag - 2001 L - mit Beleuchtung","quantity":"1","sku":"3343434","amazonSKU":"","articletype":"wandlampe","cobotFile":"Artprint","variationen":"Farbe=20 Geburtstag - 2001;Gr\u00f6\u00dfe=L - mit Beleuchtung"},{"kBestellPos":"2132","legacyOrderItemId":"2323232","title":"Holzbild Geschenk Geburtstag &quot;Back in&quot; - personalisierbar zum Hinstellen\/Aufh\u00e4ngen optional beleuchtet, Geburtstag M\u00e4dchen Geschenk 30 Geburtstag - 1991 L - ohne Beleuchtung","quantity":"1","sku":"223232","amazonSKU":"","articletype":"wandbild","cobotFile":"Artprint","variationen":"Farbe=30 Geburtstag - 1991;Gr\u00f6\u00dfe=L - ohne Beleuchtung"}],"anzahl":"3","istBezahlt":"true"}
```

But now I have the problem that json_decode still does not run. If I output the variable again, then the " are escaped again.

I have already made several attempts to suppress or undo the escaping, all without success....  The function json_last_error_msg() says that "Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded" ,here must be meant the \ before the ". If I run a json_decode in the [online tool](https://de.functions-online.com/json_decode.html) with a simple " and leave the rest as it is, it goes through, whether with or without umlauts.

What am I doing wrong? I just can't figure it out.... I hope you can have a look at this.

Best regards

**SOLUTION:**

The comments in combination have provided the solution. After getting stuck yesterday, today I looked for the solution at the source as suggested. In fact, the multilines in "cBestellHinweis" were the problem, which I solved at the source in dotliquid using ... | Replace : "\r\n",";". So I can separate the lines again later via explode. So I could apply json_decode directly without any preg_replace. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: your `cBestellHinweis` property is multilined. That is not valid in JSON.

Comment: I would recommend trying to fix this at the source, whatever creates this. Something either is or isn't JSON, and the provided text is not JSON, and "fixing" it is going to be an uphill battle.